# Partition into classes: jenks vs kmeans

Tags: r, intervals

I want to partition a vector (length around 10^5) into five classes. With the function `classIntervals` from package `classInt` I wanted to use `style = "jenks"` natural breaks but this takes an inordinate amount of time even for a much smaller vector of only 500. Setting `style = "kmeans"` executes almost instantaneously.

```
library(classInt)

my_n <- 100
set.seed(1)
x <- mapply(rnorm, n = my_n, mean = (1:5) * 5)

system.time(classIntervals(x, n = 5, style = "jenks"))
R> system.time(classIntervals(x, n = 5, style = "jenks"))
   user  system elapsed 
  13.46    0.00   13.45 

system.time(classIntervals(x, n = 5, style = "kmeans"))
R> system.time(classIntervals(x, n = 5, style = "kmeans"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02
```

What makes the Jenks algorithm so slow, and is there a faster way to run it?

If need be I will move the last two parts of the question to stats.stackexchange.com:

- Under what circumstances is kmeans a reasonable substitute for Jenks?
- Is it reasonable to define classes by running classInt on a random 1% subset of the data points?

Comment: do read the help for functions. `kmeans` uses a random set of samples as initial cluster centres. To get reproducible results set a seed via `set.seed()` and read up about k-means and local vs global minima. This is mentioned in `?classIntervals`.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I found that part soon after posting and edited the question.

Comment: I don't think there's much evidence to suggest that jenk's breaks are any better than quantiles.

Comment: @hadley: That's hard to believe. Imagine your data represents the heights of 10 adults and 90 children. It should be clear that a good clustering algorithm tells you more than stuffing them into equal-sized quantiles.

Comment: Ok, but it's pretty unusual your get data with very clear clusters like that.  Do you really think that your 100,000 points nicely cluster into only 5 clusters?! If so, I wish I could work with data like yours.

Comment: I don't know about 5 clusters, but there are definitely situations where you expect two clusters. Converting a grayscale image of part of a page into a black and white only image for optical character recognition is an excellent example for which quantiles will be very wrong, but two definite clusters are expected.

Answer (score 11):

To answer your original question:

> What makes the Jenks algorithm so slow, and is there a faster way to
>   run it?

Indeed, meanwhile there is a faster way to apply the Jenks algorithm, the `setjenksBreaks` function in the `BAMMtools` package.

However, be aware that you have to set the number of breaks differently, i.e. if you set the breaks to 5 in the the `classIntervals` function of the `classInt` package you have to set the breaks to 6 the `setjenksBreaks` function in the `BAMMtools` package to get the same results.

```
# Install and load library
install.packages("BAMMtools")
library(BAMMtools)

# Set up example data
my_n <- 100
set.seed(1)
x <- mapply(rnorm, n = my_n, mean = (1:5) * 5)

# Apply function
getJenksBreaks(x, 6)
```

The speed up is huge, i.e.

```
> microbenchmark( getJenksBreaks(x, 6, subset = NULL),  classIntervals(x, n = 5, style = "jenks"), unit="s", times=10)
Unit: seconds
                                      expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
       getJenksBreaks(x, 6, subset = NULL) 0.002824861 0.003038748 0.003270575 0.003145692 0.003464058 0.004263771    10  a 
 classIntervals(x, n = 5, style = "jenks") 2.008109622 2.033353970 2.094278189 2.103680325 2.111840853 2.231148846    10
```

Answer (score 2):

From `?BAMMtools::getJenksBreaks`

> The Jenks natural breaks method was ported to C from code found in the classInt R package.

The two programs are the same; one is faster than the other because of their implementation (C vs R).

Comment: where can I learn about the difference between jenks, fisher and so on, in classInt?