# Ranking Values by Natural Breaks (Jenks) in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if it is possible to rank values in columns by Natural Breaks(Jenks). I had figured out to do it by quantile but is there a similar method using natural breaks instead?

Here is my quantile excerpt

```
# Calculate HVI Score  
HVI_Ranking <-  DC_HVI %>%

  within(R_Temp <- as.integer(cut(Temp, quantile(Temp, probs=0:10/10), include.lowest=TRUE)))
```

This was an excerpt output using quantile that I would like to emulate with natural breaks.

```
GEOID   Temp    R_Temp
11001000100 28.9803085  2
11001000202 29.7496948  3
11001000300 28.7532024  2
11001000400 28.805212   2
11001000501 29.1443195  2
11001000502 29.0645504  2
11001000600 28.4270325  1
11001000701 28.5582047  1
11001000702 28.9018803  2
11001000801 27.427227   1
11001000802 27.7022781  1
```

Comment: Maybe 
    split {base}

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304057/partition-into-classes-jenks-vs-kmeans) might be helpful.